# On Linux OS In Python Determine if a given network interface is wifi based or just ethernet based?

Tags: python, interface, wifi, ethernet

On Linux, need in Python a way to determine if a given network interface is wifi or just ethernet (i.e. cable) based.  Working on a project where knowing the type of interface transport, if you will, is needed.  Given the modern network architecture in Linux, you can't trust that UDEV or something else has not named the interfaces to something odd, so ens* vs. wl* parsing of the interface names can be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pyric.pyw.iswireless() call from the library PyRIC.